# Intercept ActiveRecord establish_connection initialization process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Postgresql as my database and rails 3 as my middleware for a multi-tenant application.

I would like to set an environment variable containing currently logged in client id for every connection that gets created via establish_connection method.

Is there anyway I can intercept initialization process through any callbacks of establish_connection to set this environment variable?

Comment: Could you describe what you really want to achieve? What if one application connects to many different databases, what do you want to set in the env variable? And why do you want to set env variable ???

Comment: Sorry, somehow did not receive your comment in my mailbox. Yep I figured that setting environment variable is a bad practice. Basically I am building a postgres schema for every client account to ensure data privacy. However, this means I will need to change the schema_search_path for every ActiveRecord connection based on client_id of the current user. Normally I would not have like to use session information in Model but in this case I need to use this info every time a connection is established. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would lean towards separating data at the app level by something like an authority_level field.  You could then have a "verify_permission(current_user)" method run as a before_filter.

We typically do this and have a "kick_user_out" method that automatically forces a logout and emailed admin alert with non-sensitive params for the purpose of alerting admins when a privilege escalation occurs.  You get enough of those and the account gets locked as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still feel more comfortable separating the client data at db level. As keeping it at client level would mean each of my query need to have a client_id filter. Any rogue query may potentially jeopardize security. I worry more about such rogue queries then the permission level issues.